# Detecting presence of an object in an image

Tags: c++, image-processing, arduino, raspberry-pi2, opencv3.0

I'm fairly new to OpenCV and C/C++ (been coding in Java and C# though). I am working on a project(robot rather) which detects traffic lights and signs(stop sign only). Now I found a great tutorial here and used the code provided in the tutorial as it is for red coloured object detection. Since its configurable I can set it to see the traffic light just fine.

Link to the tutorial- http://opencv-srf.blogspot.in/2010/09/object-detection-using-color-seperation.html

Here is the code so far -

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  VideoCapture cap(0); //capture the video from web cam

if ( !cap.isOpened() )  // if not success, exit program
{
     cout << "Cannot open the web cam" << endl;
     return -1;
}

namedWindow("Control", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); //create a window called "Control"

int iLowH = 0;
int iHighH = 179;

int iLowS = 0; 
int iHighS = 255;

int iLowV = 0;
int iHighV = 255;

//Create trackbars in "Control" window
cvCreateTrackbar("LowH", "Control", &iLowH, 179); //Hue (0 - 179)
cvCreateTrackbar("HighH", "Control", &iHighH, 179);

cvCreateTrackbar("LowS", "Control", &iLowS, 255); //Saturation (0 - 255)
cvCreateTrackbar("HighS", "Control", &iHighS, 255);

cvCreateTrackbar("LowV", "Control", &iLowV, 255); //Value (0 - 255)
cvCreateTrackbar("HighV", "Control", &iHighV, 255);

while (1)
{
    Mat imgOriginal;

    bool bSuccess = cap.read(imgOriginal); // read a new frame from video

     if (!bSuccess) //if not success, break loop
    {
         cout << "Cannot read a frame from video stream" << endl;
         break;
    }

Mat imgHSV;

cvtColor(imgOriginal, imgHSV, COLOR_BGR2HSV); //Convert the captured frame from BGR to HSV

Mat imgThresholded;

inRange(imgHSV, Scalar(iLowH, iLowS, iLowV), Scalar(iHighH, iHighS, iHighV),  imgThresholded); //Threshold the image

 //morphological opening (remove small objects from the foreground)
erode(imgThresholded, imgThresholded, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)) );
dilate( imgThresholded, imgThresholded, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)) ); 

 //morphological closing (fill small holes in the foreground)
dilate( imgThresholded, imgThresholded, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)) ); 
erode(imgThresholded, imgThresholded, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)) );

imshow("Thresholded Image", imgThresholded); //show the thresholded image
imshow("Original", imgOriginal); //show the original image
    if (waitKey(30) == 27) //wait for 'esc' key press for 30ms. If 'esc' key is pressed, break loop
   {
        cout << "esc key is pressed by user" << endl;
        break; 
   }
}

return 0;

}
```

I've spent entire nights looking up the OpenCV documentation and other possible questions on StackOverflow but none that I found address my issue. Trust me, I'm asking this after quite a lot of stumbling here and there in my quest for answers.

So my questions are-

Q1. Since I'm new to C/C++(the tutorial code is written in C++), what possible ways are there to signal when the light is on or of? I atleast need to show on the screen that the light went off and when it came back on. I tried a few ways but none worked.(Doesn't matter if I have to convert the image to greyscale)
(Example - Stop msg displayed on screen when light is on and go when off)

Q2. How do I detect the signs and take appropriate action. Here detection is not much of a problem(lot of tutorials available, I can manage that but any tips would be appreciated), taking action upon the detection is.

Q3.***This might be off topic but is crucial to my project.*** Currently I am developing the code on my Windows PC but I intend to use this on a Raspberry Pi 3, which will in turn control a slave Arduino UNO board which controls motors. From all my research until now I've come to know that OpenCV on the RPi is used in python whereas I am coding in C/C++. So can I run my code as it was written on my PC on the RPi or do I have to first rewrite it in python and then put it on the Pi.( And oh, if you can give me further ideas on how to go on with the rest of my project that'll be great!)

I'm obviously not asking you all to teach me C++. But a few keywords or a sample code would be great. And please keep in mind that since the ultimate use of this code would be on a RPi interfacing with an Arduino, if you can keep the code in that context it would be better. Otherwise just please answer with respect to Windows, I'll modify the code one way or the other and make it work on RPi. I'm a completely self taught programmer and I'm only 17 so I'm a bit outsourced too but help from folks like you all is more than enough to keep me running.

Thanks.

Comment: I think that knowing that you're using C++ and not C may be a good starting point

Comment: My bad @Miki I have edited my question. As I told, I don't know much about the two languages... Anyways thanks. So now when I have a good starting point, where to go next?

Comment: You can ask one question per question... And go step by step... ;D. Regarding Q1, you could show some examples of on/off traffic lights... If you have some code to check for on/off (not this tutorial code which is basically useless here) we can start from that.

Comment: @Miki So that means I take two images, one with a green traffic light and one with a red one, and then compare the frames in my video feed to these images, right?

Comment: I'd start with still images and then extend to video. However, I suppose that your camera is moving, so comparing frames wouldn't help much

Comment: @Miki For the initial detection, at the start point, the robot will be stationary... So I guess I should focus on that first. But if comparing frames isn't gonna help , what shall I do?

Comment: I'd start looking for green / red blobs in the image. (now I have to go.. Good luck!)

Comment: @Miki very well, I'd start doing the same.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are many questions here. You are probably better off using processing or python for this cause you need to use it on the raspberry pi which is linux. Any header files or libraries you use that are windows based will not work in linux and unless your running ubuntu setting up opencv in linux can be a real pain. Processing is cross platform and has opencv libraries that run and are also seen as an extension of arduino code as the syntax is very similar. This is where I would start.

as for the red light here are some simple steps

pick a region of intrest "roi" for the stop sign in the center of the camera a square that is about 25-50 percent of the center of the frame then search through the roi pixel by pixel for the color red. if x percent of the roi is red there is a stop sign in front of the camera.

yes downvote the guy with working code

https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=913451218754261&set=a.138550599577664.26406.100002681733815&type=3&theater

```
 /**
   * MultipleColorTracking
   * Select 2 colors to track them separately
   *
   * It uses the OpenCV for Processing library by Greg Borenstein
   */


import gab.opencv.*;
import processing.video.*;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

Capture video;
OpenCV opencv;
PImage src;
ArrayList<Contour> contours;

int maxColors = 2;
int[] hues;
int[] colors;
int rangeWidth = 10;

PImage[] outputs;

int colorToChange = -1;

void setup() {
  video = new Capture(this, 640, 480);
  opencv = new OpenCV(this, video.width, video.height);
  contours = new ArrayList<Contour>();

  size(opencv.width + opencv.width/4 + 30, opencv.height, P2D);

  // Array for detection colors
  colors = new int[maxColors];
  hues = new int[maxColors];

  outputs = new PImage[maxColors];

  video.start();
}

void draw() {

  background(150);

  if (video.available()) {
    video.read();

  }

  // <2> Load the new frame in to OpenCV
  opencv.loadImage(video);

  // Tell OpenCV to use color information
  opencv.useColor();
  src = opencv.getSnapshot();

  // <3> Tell OpenCV to work in HSV color space.
  opencv.useColor(HSB);

  detectColors();

  // Show images
  image(src, 0, 0);
  for (int i=0; i<outputs.length; i++) {
    if (outputs[i] != null) {
      image(outputs[i], width-src.width/4, i*src.height/4, src.width/4, src.height/4);

      noStroke();
      fill(colors[i]);
      rect(src.width, i*src.height/4, 30, src.height/4);
    }
  }

  // Print text if new color expected
  textSize(20);
  stroke(255);
  fill(255);

  if (colorToChange > -1) {
    text("click to change color " + colorToChange, 10, 25);
  } else {
    text("press key [1-2] to select color", 10, 25);
  }

  displayContoursBoundingBoxes();
}

//////////////////////
// Detect Functions
//////////////////////

void detectColors() {

  for (int i=0; i<hues.length; i++) {

    if (hues[i] <= 0) continue;

    opencv.loadImage(src);
    opencv.useColor(HSB);

    // <4> Copy the Hue channel of our image into 
    //     the gray channel, which we process.
    opencv.setGray(opencv.getH().clone());

    int hueToDetect = hues[i];
    //println("index " + i + " - hue to detect: " + hueToDetect);

    // <5> Filter the image based on the range of 
    //     hue values that match the object we want to track.
    opencv.inRange(hueToDetect-rangeWidth/2, hueToDetect+rangeWidth/2);

    //opencv.dilate();
    opencv.erode();

    // TO DO:
    // Add  some image filtering to detect blobs better

    // <6> Save the processed image for reference.
    outputs[i] = opencv.getSnapshot();
  }

  if (outputs[0] != null) {

    opencv.loadImage(outputs[0]);
    contours = opencv.findContours(true,true);
  }
}

void displayContoursBoundingBoxes() {

  for (int i=0; i<contours.size(); i++) {

    Contour contour = contours.get(i);
    Rectangle r = contour.getBoundingBox();

    if (r.width < 20 || r.height < 20)
      continue;

    stroke(255, 0, 0);
    fill(255, 0, 0, 150);
    strokeWeight(2);
    rect(r.x, r.y, r.width, r.height);
  }
}

//////////////////////
// Keyboard / Mouse
//////////////////////

void mousePressed() {

  if (colorToChange > -1) {

    color c = get(mouseX, mouseY);
    println("r: " + red(c) + " g: " + green(c) + " b: " + blue(c));

    int hue = int(map(hue(c), 0, 255, 0, 180));

    colors[colorToChange-1] = c;
    hues[colorToChange-1] = hue;

    println("color index " + (colorToChange-1) + ", value: " + hue);
  }
}

void keyPressed() {

  if (key == '1') {
    colorToChange = 1;

  } else if (key == '2') {
    colorToChange = 2;

  }
}

void keyReleased() {
  colorToChange = -1; 
}
```

after you detect the color you compare it with your roi if enough of your roi has detected the color then there is a stop sign! create a bool value for seeing a stop sign and when it's true process the rest of your code.

Comment: Hmmm can OpenCV run on Kali? That's the only linux I have right now. Any tips on how to pick the roi? And I guess that code snippet would be inside a loop, right?

Comment: See my explanation that is now above my other answer. Both of these code examples work and are a part of the opencv_processing example library. processing can export as java or exe straight to linux so you should be familiar enough to work with it and there are tutorials for using the processing library raw within java as well. Not to mention you can easily import serial i/o for spi control of the arduino through processing using the same syntax. I've already done projects like yours on a much grander scale using processing and arduino this stuff is easy to use and it just works.

Answer (score 0):

example explaining roi using opencv processing library. You just download processing 2.0 or higher and import the library using the easy import tool opencv for processing. I'm not going to do your whole project for you. Create a static roi in the center of the frame and if detect color is with in the roi you have a stop sign in front of you see the working code below to detect threshold colors.

```
import gab.opencv.*;

PImage src;
OpenCV opencv;

int roiWidth = 300;
int roiHeight = 300;

boolean useROI = true;

void setup() {
  src = loadImage("test.jpg");
  opencv = new OpenCV(this, src);
  size(opencv.width, opencv.height);
}

void draw() {
  opencv.loadImage(src);

  if (useROI) {
    opencv.setROI(mouseX, mouseY, roiWidth, roiHeight);
  }

  opencv.findCannyEdges(20,75);
  image(opencv.getOutput(), 0, 0);
}

// toggle ROI on and off
void keyPressed() {
  useROI = !useROI;

  if (!useROI) {
    opencv.releaseROI();
  }
}
```